# Count number of months since start in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` which contains data from a car selling company. The data frame contains the dates and the number of sells for specific dates. Each salesperson has a `staff_id`. A dummy `inital_sell` indicates which day is the first working day of the person.

Now I want to add a column `months_since_start` which adds for each day the month since the person started to work. Then I can use the `sells` and the `months_since_start` columns to plot the mean sells for each month since the salespersons started to work (sells for the 1st month for each salesperson, in the 2nd month...). As some days and months are missing (e.g., during holidays as shown in the bottom part of the example), I can't simply add a sequence to get `months_since_start`.

```
date        year    month   staff_id   sells  initial_sell   months_since_start
2014-11-11  2014    11      1          3      1              1
2014-11-12  2014    11      1          1      0              1
2014-11-14  2014    11      1          1      0              1
2014-11-15  2014    11      1          2      0              1
...                     
2014-12-10  2014    12      1          2      0              1
2014-12-11  2014    12      1          1      0              2
...                     
2014-12-23  2014    12      2          1      1              1
2015-02-02  2015    2       2          4      0              2
2015-02-03  2015    2       2          1      0              2
...                     
2015-03-23  2015    3       2          3      0              4
...
```

Can someone help me how to get the `month_since_start` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input is assumed to be sorted by `staff_id` and `date`, as in the question, and shown at the end in the Note.  Define a `months` function which given a sorted vector of dates for a staff member returns the months since start (i.e. since the first date) for that member.  Then use `tapply` to apply it to each staff member.   `tapply` returns a list sorted by `staff_id` so unravel it with `unlist`. No packages are used.

```
Months <- function(date) {
  with(as.POSIXlt(date), 12 * (year - year[1]) + (mon - mon[1]) + (mday >= mday[1]))
}

transform(DF, months_since_start = unlist(tapply(date, staff_id, FUN = Months)))
```

giving:

```
         date year month staff_id sells initial_sell months_since_start
1  2014-11-11 2014    11        1     3            1                  1
2  2014-11-12 2014    11        1     1            0                  1
3  2014-11-14 2014    11        1     1            0                  1
4  2014-11-15 2014    11        1     2            0                  1
5  2014-12-10 2014    12        1     2            0                  1
6  2014-12-11 2014    12        1     1            0                  2
7  2014-12-23 2014    12        2     1            1                  1
8  2015-02-02 2015     2        2     4            0                  2
9  2015-02-03 2015     2        2     1            0                  2
10 2015-03-23 2015     3        2     3            0                  4
```

**Alternative** An alternative using `ave` instead of `tapply` is as follows.  `Months` is as above.  `MonthsDF` invokes `Months` but accepts row numbers rather than the date itself.  This solution still assumes that the data is sorted by `date` within `staff_id` but since `ave` returns its output in the same order as the input it need not be sorted by `staff_id`.  The downside of `ave` is that it does not handle `"Date"` class data in the manner needed here which is why we used row numbers as the input to `MonthsDF`:

```
MonthsDF <- function(ix) Months(DF$date[ix])
transform(DF, months_since_start = ave(seq_along(date), staff_id, FUN = MonthsDF))
```

**Note:** This input was used:

```
Lines <- "date        year    month   staff_id   sells  initial_sell   
2014-11-11  2014    11      1          3      1              
2014-11-12  2014    11      1          1      0              
2014-11-14  2014    11      1          1      0              
2014-11-15  2014    11      1          2      0                            
2014-12-10  2014    12      1          2      0              
2014-12-11  2014    12      1          1      0              
2014-12-23  2014    12      2          1      1              
2015-02-02  2015    2       2          4      0              
2015-02-03  2015    2       2          1      0              
2015-03-23  2015    3       2          3      0"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date)

# in the question the input is already sorted by staff_id and date so
# the next two lines are not really needed but if we had non-sorted data
# then we should first sort it like this to be in the same form as in question
o <- with(DF, order(staff_id, date))
DF <- DF[o, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
# some sample data
df <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'), as.Date('2014-04-04'), by = 30), 3),
                 staff_id = rep(1:3, each = 4))
```

so `df` looks like:

```
> head(df)
        date staff_id
1 2014-01-01        1
2 2014-01-31        1
3 2014-03-02        1
4 2014-04-01        1
5 2014-01-01        2
6 2014-01-31        2
```

Now use `dplyr` to `group_by` `staff_id`, and then use `mutate` to add a column. Within `mutate`, set `months_since_start` to the `time_length` of the `interval` from the `min`imum date (for each `staff_id`, thanks to `group_by`) and the `date` of each row. Set the `unit` of `time_length` to `month`.

```
df %>% group_by(staff_id) %>% 
  mutate(months_since_start = time_length(interval(min(date), 
                                                   date), 
                                          unit = 'month'))
```

You get:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
Groups: staff_id [3]

         date staff_id months_since_start
       (date)    (int)              (dbl)
1  2014-01-01        1          0.0000000
2  2014-01-31        1          0.9677419
3  2014-03-02        1          2.0322581
4  2014-04-01        1          3.0000000
5  2014-01-01        2          0.0000000
6  2014-01-31        2          0.9677419
7  2014-03-02        2          2.0322581
8  2014-04-01        2          3.0000000
9  2014-01-01        3          0.0000000
10 2014-01-31        3          0.9677419
11 2014-03-02        3          2.0322581
12 2014-04-01        3          3.0000000
```

If you'd like completed months, wrap `time_length` in `floor`.